# Is it possible to pass data from LWC to a Screen Flow in the same lightning page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow

I have a LWC which shows the availability of apartments based on a building. Basically they asked me if there is a way to "link" this component to a screen flow which would be placed in the same lightning page, and the point is to select the apartments on my LWC, and use those selected apartments in the Screen Flow, for another process. Is that possible? I've been looking around and all I could find was LWC embedded in Screen Flows, but I couldn't find a way to send data from a LWC to a Screen Flow, if they are separated. Any help/links would help, and if this is not possible, is there a workaround? I don't think combining both would be a solution because they are still made for different things. It's just convenient to take advantage of the display of apartments and not use a simple combobox in the flow.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_interactions_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: @Damecek can't find information on how to get it working with Screen Flows though. Don't know if that's possible

Comment: @joacoiudica were you able to find anything for this?  Needing the same thing :-D

Comment: @derekshull no, I didn't... I ended up developing a new LWC to use specifically inside the Screen Flow: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_flow_screens